# javaFX TableCell with event

Tags: javafx, tablecell, eventhandler, tablecolumn

what is the correct way to add EventHander to a TableCell?

at first I only had these two lines

```
@FXML private TableColumn EANCol;
...
EANCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<MyRow, String>("EAN"));
```

and everything worked until I tried adding an event

```
EventHandler eh = new EventHandler<MouseEvent>(){
    @Override
    public void handle(MouseEvent mouseEvent) {
        if(mouseEvent.getButton().equals(MouseButton.PRIMARY)){
            if(mouseEvent.getClickCount() == 2){
                System.out.print("Double clicked ");
                System.out.println(mouseEvent.getTarget().toString());
            }
        }
    }
};

EANCol.setCellFactory(new Callback<TableColumn, TableCell>() {
    @Override
    public TableCell call(TableColumn p) {
        TableCell cell = new TableCell();
        cell.setOnMouseClicked(eh);
        return cell;
    }
});
```

Problem: now I can double click on it, but the whole column is empty, with null as value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A table cell created with the default constructor doesn't actually do anything in its `updateItem(...)` method to cause anything to be displayed. There is a [`DEFAULT_CELL_FACTORY`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TableColumn.html#DEFAULT_CELL_FACTORY) defined in `TableColumn` that represents a factory generating "default" table cells (i.e. displaying the string version of the content). So if you want the default behavior with an event handler added you can do:

```
EANCol.setCellFactory(new Callback<TableColumn<?,?>, TableCell<?,?>>() {
    @Override
    public TableCell call(TableColumn<?,?> p) {
        TableCell<?,?> cell = TableColumn.DEFAULT_CELL_FACTORY.call(p);
        cell.setOnMouseClicked(eh);
        return cell;
    }
});
```

Comment: thank you very much for such a fast reply. it works now